# Pelican: customizing index.html by reading metadata from YAML

Tags: python, pelican

I am looking to build a personal CV site using Pelican. Since I am not really targeting a blog site, I want a somewhat different index.html and it should be easy to maintain. I know I can directly make the template the way I want at the very least, but then it involves directly modifying html which defeats the purpose of using a static content generator.

I am thinking to represent the data using a YAML file, and pass in extra data to jinja2 only when index.html is being generated. So my question is, how should I configure a plugin so that it only applies to some specific files and alters the output?